# i have build error when i build next js redirect 500 internal error page

Tags: redirect, next.js, build

I got this build error when I try npm run build:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /500
    at C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:409:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1345:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1205:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\myfile\Perfetto\website\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:66:29)
```

this is my /500 page:

```
export default function Custom500() {
  return <h1>500 - Server-side error occurred</h1>;
}
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: "/",
      permanent: true, // triggers 308
    },
  };
}
```

what is this error?
how can I fix this?